# Resize terminal emulator windows with ctrl+super+arrow doesn't work any more

Tags: shortcut-keys, window, resize

I used to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd> to resize my windows to a particular side of the screen. But since a fresh install this doesn't work any more. Has anything changed? I cannot remember manually adding these shortcuts.

Comment: Did you change to a different version / flavor of Ubuntu? What version / flavor are you using now? (And which were you using before if you changed?)

Comment: Would it be that you need to install Compiz Config Settings Manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was just a switch on the keyboard that was in "Gaming Mode".
Anyway sometimes this issue comes from another problem so here i explain how to fix this issue :

In terminal :

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep -i compiz
sudo apt-get install compiz compiz-core compiz-gnome compiz-plugins-default compizconfig-settings-manager libcompizconfig0 python-compizconfig --reinstall
```

**This will fix most issues with keyboard shortcuts.**

---

### Sometimes you still have keyboard/shortcuts issues. Then there are few options left:

**1. First Start with Unplugging your keyboard and plug it back in.**

**2. Reinstall/Reinitialize your keyboard layout :**

In terminal :

```
sudo apt-get install console-data
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-data
```

Or use :

```
dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

Through the graphical interface :

- Click the Settings menu > System Settings:
- Next, go to Personal > Text Entry:
- Click the **+** button to choose a new layout:

---

**3. Use onscreen keyboard to test if the shortcuts work there :**

You can think why not try this first ? Well basically because this is not the first thing that comes up when my keyboard don't work since it should work.

In terminal type:

```
onboard
```

Through the graphical interface :

- Click the Settings menu > System Settings.
- Next, go to System > Universal Access.
- Select the Typing tab, and then switch the On-Screen Keyboard option to ON.

Some usefull shortcuts for Ubuntu : [Useful keyboard shortcuts](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-keyboard-shortcuts.html)

---

**4. If ALL the above don't work :**

---

### Reset **Ubuntu Unity** to it's Default Settings :

```
dconf reset -f /
```